# Studying Fourier Analysis on sphere S^2

Tags: group-isomorphism, quotient-spaces, spheres

For special orthogonal group $SO(3)$,

Define a maximal torus of $SO(3)$ as $K$, by

$$K:=\{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos x & -\sin x & 0 \\
    \sin x & \cos x & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
 : 0 \leq x \lt 2\pi \}$$.

Now we consider double coset $K/SO(3)/K$, by
$$K/SO(3)/K:= \{KgK: g \in SO(3) \}$$ where $ KgK:=\{k_1 g k_2: k_1, k_2 \in K \}$.

Book explains that $K/SO(3)/K$ is isomorphic to colatitude $\phi \in [0. \pi]$ of Sphere $S^2$. It gives a map $KgK \to S^2$ by $k_1 g k_2 \mapsto k_1 g n=k_1 x$ for some $x \in S^2$ with north pole $n=(0, 0, 1)$.

However, I cannot show these two spaces are isomorphic in rigorous way. Could anybody explain this isomorphism?

Comment: By orbit-stabilizer, $SO(3)/K\simeq S^2$ via $gK\mapsto gn$ where $n=(0,0,1)$ and $K=\mathrm{Stab}(n)\cong SO(2)$. Then $K\backslash SO(3)/K$ is basically the orbit space of $K$ acting on $S^2$, which is of course all the lattitudes around the sphere. The element $KgK$ corresponds to the lattitudinal circle containing $gn$.

Comment: Ohh I got it. Thanks a lot for your help